# What is the use of autoRehydrate in redux-persist and why it was removed on v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I couldn't find anything on the GitHub page of [ReduxPersist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

I have a piece of code I'm trying to understand and as this `autoRehydrate` was removed, I would like to know how the code should be implemented with **version 5** of `redux-persist`.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { autoRehydrate, persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const middleWare = [thunk];

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleWare)(createStore);

 export default configureStore = (onComplete) => {
  const store = autoRehydrate()(createStoreWithMiddleware)(reducers);
  persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, onComplete);

  return store;
};
```

I've found some tutorials, but it just says this `autoRehydrate` must be there but doesn't explain what it actually does.

Answer (score 5):

`autoRehydrate` means calling for the `persist/REHYDRATE` action to read the *persisted state from the disk* (which you have persisted before) which can be merged back to the original state.

In the migration guide from v4 to v5, they have introduced a [PersistGate](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md).

*This delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux.*

Therefore all the rehydration actions will be handled by it under the hood.